# Oracle: Delete Duplicate Rows, Comparison Excluding ID Column

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, data-cleaning

I have an Oracle table as Follows:

```
ID       A      B      C
1       aaa    bbb    ccc
2       aaa    bbb    ccc
3       ddd    eee    fff
4       ddd    eee    fff
5       aha    bqb    ccd
6       aaa    bbb    ccc
```

I am looking to delete every duplicate row, even if they different IDs.

The intended result is the following:

```
ID       A      B      C
4       ddd    eee    fff
5       aha    bqb    ccd
6       aaa    bbb    ccc
```

I am indifferent about keeping the smallest or largest ID.

In other words, i would not mind the following:

```
ID       A      B      C
1       aaa    bbb    ccc
3       ddd    eee    fff
5       aha    bqb    ccd
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you create a View, which will just trim the results by grouping them: `create or replace view no_duplicates as select A, B, C, COUNT(*) from Table group by A,B,C having count(*) > 1;` - then you can use the view to create a table with no duplicates etc. is this one time job or it should happen more often?

Comment: it's a one time job

Comment: Not possible for me to test this one: `delete table where rowid > (select min(rowid) from table where (A,B,C) IN (select A, B, C from Table group by A,B,C having count(*) > 1))` - does it do it's job ?

Comment: Corrected and tested: `delete table 
where rowid <> (select min(rowid) from table where (A,B,C) IN (select A,B,C from table group by A,B,C having count(*) > 1))
and (A,B,C) in (select A,B,C from table group by A,B,C having count(*) > 1)` - Ignore my previous comment. Before committing, try it over two pairs of A,B,C values and verify that is worked.